# backup variable

Tags: java, variables, backup

in my JAVA program I scan folders every hour an check those for changes. If there's a change I receive a unique number to identify this file. These data are stored in a field variable. So I need to store the data locally for the case of restart or crash.

My Datastructure:

```
Map<String, Long> currentFiles = new HashMap<String, Long>();
Map<String, Long> prevFiles = new HashMap<String, Long>();
```

Which backup should I use? The data should be save against modifications. The data aren't confidential.

Comment: a database, a file, a cloud storage service, a fax machine (more difficult to reupload the data though)... There are many options.

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/ That might the task of checking for changes easier.

Comment: +1 for the facsimile suggestion. I´d add a hex dump which one can re-enter using DEBUG.COM as often as one wishes.

Comment: I really like the "backup" tag here...

Comment: @Averroes I thought about properties. But they are easy to modify. Aren't they?

Comment: @Tharmar sure they are. But anything written to a disc can be modified for someone decided to. Maybe you can save it to a file with a checksum or hash or something like that. It still modifable but you can tell if it was modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply serialize and deserialize your datastructure, it certainly looks Serializable. [Tip](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/)

Or if you prefer more robust solutions, you can create DB tables with simple DBs (outside the process of your app), so it can survive the crashes, and reload your datastructure. (For example some simple Java based DBs: [JavaDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html), [h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/))

Comment: thank you, I'll take a look at the JavaDB. sounds suiteable

Answer (score 2):

Why not try [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) in Java 7? You will have no need to use custom data structure.

Comment: Cool, didn't know this exists. BTW, it's [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html)

Comment: @assylias I have to use JDK 1.6
The DirectoryWatcher is already implemented

Comment: @Tharmar Storing the details in a file will probably be the quickest and lightest. Using a DB is more robust.

Comment: If you dont want to change existing implementation serialize the data whenever it is modified as data is not sensitive